# Happy.js - adding a message below submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, happy.js

Awesome people of Stack Overflow,

I'm trying to use Happy.js for validating my form, and it works fine. However, since my form is long and the submit button is at the very bottom of the form, I need a way to let the user know that there a errors on the form.

I'd love some help adding this functionality. Maybe unhiding a div right below the submit button or something like that.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form name="data" action="#" method="POST" id="JumpstartForm">
<label for="f1" class="control-label">First Name<span class='required'>*</span>    </label>

<input title="First Name" type="text" id="f1" name="First_Name" class="input-large" value="" size="25" />        

<div class="centered"><input type="submit" id="submitSignup" value="Submit" class="green-button" /></div>

</form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.democracy-nc.org/jumpstart/js/happy.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.democracy-nc.org/jumpstart/js/happy.methods.js"></script>
```

Here's the js bit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#JumpstartForm').isHappy({
      fields: {
        // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
        // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.
        '#f1': {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please enter your first name'
        },
      }  
    });
  });
```

I created a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcasalett/E9Lq7/1/

Live page: http://democracy-nc.org/jumpstart/index.html

First post, so please be kind. Thanks!

Comment: you can always scroll the page up to where the form is on submit :)

Comment: wouldn't be better to use a scroll up to the first error, instead of forcing the user to scroll anyway after reading your message under the submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need it's to use the callback that the plugin provide, called unHappy that it's called when the validation fails for any reason. 
For other options you can check the Happy.js mainpage http://happyjs.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#JumpstartForm').isHappy({
      fields: {
        // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
        // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.
        '#f1': {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please enter your first name'
        },
      unHappy: function () {
            //here you can show a div, or scroll to the last error.
        },
      }  
    });
  });
```

Updated jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E9Lq7/4/

Comment: I think this is what I've been looking for. I'll try it out. Thank you!